# Kernel 2D Convolution of signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, convolution

I want to implement 2d kernel convolution of a signal in MATLAB. This is essentially a nonlinear quadratic filter of a signal (not image) as described by the formula below:

[image]

where k2(t1,t2) is a 2-dimensional convolution kernel. x is a 1d [N,1] signal vector & y is the output [N,1] signal.

So far, I've been doing this by a very brute force, non-elegant fashion. I was wondering if I could use the MATLAB `filter2`/`conv2` functions to do this more effectively! I know these functions are meant for image processing, which I don't know too much about, so I was hoping someone could help!

Comment: Are `M` and `N` the same?

Comment: No, M is the kernel size (memory of the system). N is the signal length. Ballpark figures, M=30 bins, N=10,000 bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when using `diag(conv2(x,x,k));` is that you are calculating something much larger (the whole 2d matrix) and then you keep only the diagonal. It could be expensive depending on the size of your signals. You can try with

```
n = 500; m = 50;

x = rand(n,1);
k2 = rand(m,m);

tic; res1 = diag(conv2(x,x,k2)); toc;

tic;
res2 = zeros(n+m-1,1);
for k = 1:n+m-1
    imin = k+1-min(k,m); imax = min(k,n);
    jmin = max(1,k-n+1); jmax = min(k,m);
    res2(k) = x(imax:-1:imin)'*k2(jmin:jmax,jmin:jmax)*x(imax:-1:imin);
end
toc;
norm(res1-res2)
```

It works faster than the other option for many cases I have tried. One ouput can is, for instance

```
>> script
Elapsed time is 0.012753 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.006541 seconds.

ans =

   1.5059e-12
```

I do not know how large are your signals or your kernel, so you can try.

Comment: Ballpark figures, M=30 bins, N=10,000 bins.

Comment: @DankMasterDan Don't try conv2 with that sizes. It will probably never end in a normal computer.

Comment: @DankMasterDan With a small modification it can be more efficient. Just add the parenthesis to forche matlab the matrix vector multiplication with the vector that is not transposed before the other one.  

    `x(imax:-1:imin)'*(k2(jmin:jmax,jmin:jmax)*x(imax:-1:imin));`  

It is always faster that without the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks sebas! Its not as elegent as the solution i envisioned, but it cut my computational time down by half!

Comment: You are welcome. Next time you can tag your question also with 'algorithm', and you will probably take the attention of better programmers than me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as follows

```
y=diag(conv2(k,x*x.'));
```

or

```
y=diag(conv2(x,x,k));
```

Comment: True optimization of this would require knowledge of the relative sizes of x and k.

Answer (score 0):

For the sizes you mentioned, it could  be worthwile using FFTs, although this is equivalent to cyclic convolution, so you would have to make sure N includes enough zero-padding. I assume this below.

Because of separability, you only need a 1D fft on x

```
  X=fft(x);
  K=fft2(k,N,N);

  XX=X*X.';

  ytmp=ifft2(XX.*K);
  y=diag(ytmp);
```

As sebas points out, you are discarding all but the diagonal of ytmp, so there is some wasted computation. If you are going to be repeating this for many signals x of length N, you can curb that waste by pre-computing a IDFT matrix,

```
  Afft=ifft2(eye(N)).';
```

Then, instead of computing `ytmp`, you can compute the diagonal of the ifft directly by doing

```
  y=sum(Afft2.*ifft( XX.*(K.')) );
```

Even if you aren't repeating the computation for multiple x, the NlogN efficiency of the FFT plus avoiding loops might still make up for the waste.

Comment: do you need to get real(ytmp) after inverse fft?

Comment: I don't know if a real-valued result is to be expected. That depends on the symmetry of k, and the OP hasn't told us that. But if the output is expected to be real-valued, then yes, you would have to discard any floating point residual in the imaginary part, just as you do with ifft() et al.